# Why am I getting undefined variable errors in Laravel method?

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a Laravel method in my PageController to send emails when form data is sent like the following:

```
public function sendMessage(Request $request)
{

    $name = $request->input('name');
    $email = $request->input('email');
    $message_content = $request->input('message');

    // email message
    Mail::raw($message_content, function ($message) 
    {
        $message->from($email, $name);
        // $message->to(env('APP_ADMIN_EMAIL'));
        $message->to("myemail@mail.com");
        $message->subject('Website Message');
    });

    return "message sent";

}
```

But I get this error when the method is called:

> ErrorException Undefined variable: email

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to pass the variables to the closure:

```
Mail::raw($message_content, function ($message) use ($email, $name)
{
    $message->from($email, $name);
    $message->to("myemail@mail.com");
    $message->subject('Website Message');
});
```

See docs: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php